# SSH Permission denied when subnet is /31

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ssh

I am trying to make a point to point ipv4 link with a device running Ubuntu 18.04 . if I set the device to 192.168.1.48/31 and in then OSX I set my ethernet dongle to 192.168.1.49/31, I am able to ping the device, but I am unable to ssh to it. I get  `Permission Denied`

If I change both of these to a /24, I am able to ssh without changing anything else about the configuration.

Any idea why I am unable to do this?

Comment: Speculation, perhaps worthy of a test: if you don't configure an IP address on the .48 device at all, just connect the cable and get a layer 1 link, you might still believe you are able to ping .48 from the machine at .49 because /31 isn't a valid netmask for IPv4 over Ethernet and the behavior you're seeing an artifact of that.

Comment: What happens if you set OSX to .49/31 or to .47/31

Comment: I think you better provide a screenshot of the terminal window (or at least full copy of the content in a code block).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: 
in traditional terms, The IP scheme is wrong, you need a network identifier and broadcast address.

- The valid subnet would be a `/30`. (`255.255.255.252`)
- The network number is `192.168.1.48` `/30`
- The two valid IP addresses are `.49` and `.50`
- And the broadcast address would be `192.168.1.51`.

Apparently since 2000 with rfc3021, and implemented since linux kernel 2.6.34, /31 notation is a thing. Just to be clear, I have never actually seen this implemented

Cisco equipment seems to also support it. But both seem to state **only on point-to-point links**.

I saw some references at linuxquestions.org stating that you need to bring it up as a point-to-point using:

```
ifconfig eth0 pointtopoint <IPADDR>
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3021

Comment: @grawity is correct..I can not find a definitive answer for whether macos supports it

Comment: @kevan Lannister, the /31 subnet seems like it was meant for conservation of public IP addresses. Benefiting ISP/CLECs and large corporations that were assigned public IP blocks. If you do not fit into one of those categories, and are using private ip numbers, I don't see a reason to even use it...

Comment: Also, the TCP/IP stack of the OS **must** support it. Windows seems to be a no, Mac OS...? I don't have any Mac machines to test it on